# URL Rewriting issue after uploading to server

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have the following URL...

```
site.com/dealers/company-name/906/2
```

and I have the following in my .htaccess...

```
RewriteRule ^dealers/(.[^/]*)/([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?/?$ dealers.php?dealer=$1&did=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

This works beautifully locally. But when I upload it to my server it doesn't.

It does properly redirect me to the dealers.php page, but I can not access the variables at all. I just get Undefined index: dealer, or Undefined index: did.

I should add that all of my other redirects on the site are currently working fine.

Can someone help?

Code to access parameter...

```
$dealerID = $_GET['did'];
```

Comment: Yeah, but they are optional. I set a default in code if it isn't present. And, if I put the third option in there it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the PHP code where you attempt to access the URL query parameters (ie, the code triggering the errors)

Comment: Yes rewrite engine is on. I have several other rewrites that work perfectly and this one, even though I can't get to the variables, still rewrites to the proper page.

Comment: Interesting! Give the `DPI` flag a try, though I don't think it's at fault: `[L,DPI]`. Also try `Options -Multiviews` before the rule.

Comment: Neither produced a result. I think you are on to something though. When I read about what MultiViews does and then I see this... [PHP_SELF] => /dealers.php/202-truck-and-equipment/906/2. 

It should not be appending the php to the dealers folder.

Comment: @zx81 the problem did end up being related to MultiViews. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this before the rule:

```
Options -Multiviews
```